# Backbone vs. Angular: mobile webapp + memory management

Tags: javascript, angularjs, backbone.js

I know it feels like I'm going into the which-MVC-JS-framework-is-better-than-the-other-ones useless debate between developpers.

But in my case, I have 2 very specific questions that are little documented on the web IMHO:

- I am worried about **memory leaks** in Angular. Is it actually a concern or does Backbone has the same problematics for the same use cases? (I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/databinding-in-angularjs/9693933) by the way)
- We'll also develop a **mobile version** of our web app. For sure we'll also use some MVC JS there. Is there one library that is really not recommended for web mobile? (compatibility, memory usage, loadtimes etc.)

I am currently considering Backbone and Angular, but if it really makes sense, I am open to other ones. It may be clear in the way I formulate my questions that I have a better opinion on Backbone at the moment (for several reasons I won't detail here).

Thanks for support

Comment: Angular JS is much better than Backbone if you are developing your web applications which has not more than 1000 components in your page. 
What is unique with angular JS is it uses dirty checking and it helps in continuous updation of your view but this in turn will also bog down your application if it contains too many components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so first off, The typical way you end up having leaks in AngularJS is by referencing methods inside a controller via some global variable which keeps your controller alive for the duration of the application, or by not cleaning up manually applied javascript events when destroying scopes. So if you make sure you stay in AngularJS the entire time and you're not trying to step out to do some none angular stuff and then try to find a way to get back into angularjs you shouldn't have an issue.

I think AngularJS is the perfect language to use for mobile dev because it's a full stack language and because of all the 2 way data binding it will end up feeling much more like a native application as it will exist entirely in one page load. Not to mention it's capabilities dwarf backbone.

To answer your question there is a great mobile framework that is being dev call Ionic which uses AngularJS and they've recently gotten a round of funding.

http://ionicframework.com/

Comment: angular is not a language ,it's a framework,javascript is the language.I cant vet for ionic though.